# Android compose TextField with Image using InlineTextContent

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing an Android app using Jetpack Compose.

I want to implement a TextField. This TextField should display a small emoji or image instead of text when a specific token is entered.

You can find such a case in the Slack app. Slack app supports custom emojis in addition to regular emojis.

I discovered InlineTextContent as a hint.

```kotlin
val inlineContentMap = mapOf(
    "ab_12" to emojiImage("https://c.tenor.com/Rd6ULrCRvlQAAAAd/tenor.gif")
)

var inputText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
BasicTextField(
    value = inputText,
    onValueChange = {
        inputText = it
    },
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .border(1.dp, Color.LightGray, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
        .padding(8.dp),
    textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 16.sp).copy(color = Color.Transparent),
    visualTransformation = EmojiVisualTransformation,
    decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier,
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart
        ) {
            val annotatedString = replaceTokens(inputText)
            Text(
                text = annotatedString,
                style = TextStyle(fontSize = 16.sp),
                inlineContent = inlineContentMap
            )
            innerTextField()
        }
    }
)
```

and here are other functions:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun emojiImage(imgUrl: String) =
    InlineTextContent(Placeholder(16.sp, 16.sp, PlaceholderVerticalAlign.TextCenter)) {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
            .components {
                add(ImageDecoderDecoder.Factory())
            }
            .build()
        Image(
            painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
                model = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
                    .data(data = imgUrl)
                    .build(),
                imageLoader = imageLoader
            ),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp),
        )
    }

private fun replaceTokens(input: String): AnnotatedString {
    val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
        val regex = Regex("\\{:(\\w+_\\d+):\\}")
        var currentIndex = 0
        regex.findAll(input).forEach { matchResult ->
            val token = matchResult.groupValues[1]
            val tokenIndex = matchResult.range.first
            val tokenLength = matchResult.value.length
            append(input.substring(currentIndex, tokenIndex))
            appendInlineContent(id = token)
            currentIndex = tokenIndex + tokenLength
        }
        append(input.substring(currentIndex, input.length))
    }
    return annotatedString
}
```

Here is the VisualTransformation:

```kotlin
object EmojiVisualTransformation: VisualTransformation {

    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        val originText = text.text

        val annotatedString = replaceTokens(originText)

        return TransformedText(annotatedString, EmojiOffsetMapping(originText, annotatedString.text))
    }
}

data class EmojiOffsetMapping(
    private val origin: String,
    private val transformed: String,
): OffsetMapping {

    private val tokenPositionRanges = mutableListOf<IntRange>()

    init {
        val regex = Regex("\\{:(\\w+_\\d+):\\}")
        regex.findAll(origin).forEach { matchResult ->
            val tokenPosition = matchResult.range
            tokenPositionRanges.add(tokenPosition)
        }
    }

    private fun getTransformedOffset(offset: Int): Int {
        if (offset == 0) {
            return 0
        }

        var newOffset = offset
        tokenPositionRanges.forEachIndexed { index, tokenRange ->
            if (tokenRange.first + 1 <= offset && offset <= tokenRange.last + 1) {
                return index + 1
            }

            newOffset = newOffset - tokenRange.count() + 1
        }

        return newOffset
    }

    override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
//        return getTransformedOffset(offset)
        return offset
    }

    override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
        return offset
    }
}
```

[image]

This code works only in very simple cases and often crashes in most cases.

While InlineTextContent makes it easy to display images between strings, the problem lies with the cursor.

In the case of the tokens I'm using in my format {:d_1:}, {:ab_10:}, they occupy 7 to 9 or more characters, resulting in invisible spaces even though they appear replaced by a single image.

This makes the cursor behavior very erratic.

In fact, I'm not sure if using InlineTextContent and VisualTransformation is the right approach anymore.

How can I implement this TextField effectively?"

---

#### [EDIT 1]

One more question:

In the Slack app, placing the cursor directly after an emoji and pressing the backspace key deletes the emoji.

However, in the current implementation, instead of deleting the emoji, pressing the backspace key deletes the last character of the token, causing the emoji to revert and the token to be exposed.

For example, instead of deleting the entire "{:ab_12:}" token, only the last curly brace '}' is deleted, leaving "{:ab_12:" exposed.

How should we handle deleting the entire token when pressing the backspace key?

---

#### [EDIT 2]

To enable the emoji to be deleted properly when the user places the cursor directly after it and presses the backspace key, more complex cursor control is needed.

I'm not sure if this is even possible. Typically, in BasicTextField, once the backspace key is pressed, the text is already deleted, making it difficult to determine which character was deleted.

After much deliberation, I thought that perhaps assigning an ImageSpan representing a single empty character (Unicode like `U+0020`) rather than assigning a String containing the token to the value of BasicTextField might be a better way to handle the backspace key.

I also attempted to pass TextFieldValue instead of String to the value of BasicTextField, but this also failed to achieve the goal.

Although I succeeded in replacing the token with an image in AnnotatedString when creating TextFieldValue in onValueChange, when the string replaced with the Unicode empty character is called again in onValueChange, the position information annotated in AnnotatedString is reset.

While it's evident that this functionality is implemented in major commercial apps like Slack, finding related libraries is challenging. How could they have implemented it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `EmojiOffsetMapping`, for your `originalToTransformed` method, you should calculate the cursor position in the transformed text, which means taking into account the replaced images. For each token, the length will be reduced to 1 (since the image takes only one position), no matter how many characters the original token has.

```bash
Cursor Mapping: Original ↔ Transformed
┌────────────────────┐        ┌────────────────────┐
│ Original Text      │        │ Transformed Text   │
│ {:ab_12:} hello... │   ↔    │  hello....      │
│          ↑         │        │   ↑                │
└────────────────────┘        └────────────────────┘
Cursor at token end          Cursor at image end
```

```kotlin
override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
    var transformedOffset = offset
    for (tokenRange in tokenPositionRanges) {
        if (offset > tokenRange.last) {
            // Cursor is beyond the current token, subtract the token's length
            // minus one because it is replaced by a single image.
            transformedOffset -= tokenRange.count() - 1
        } else if (offset > tokenRange.first) {
            // Cursor is within the current token, place it right after the image.
            return tokenRange.first + 1
        }
    }
    return transformedOffset
}
```

In `transformedToOriginal`, you need to do the reverse, finding the correct position in the original text when the cursor is moved within the transformed text.

```kotlin
override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
    var originalOffset = offset
    var addedLength = 0
    for (tokenRange in tokenPositionRanges) {
        val tokenLength = tokenRange.count()
        if (originalOffset <= tokenRange.first + addedLength) {
            break
        }
        // Add back the length of the tokens replaced by images.
        addedLength += tokenLength - 1
    }
    return originalOffset + addedLength
}
```

---

> In the Slack app, placing the cursor directly after an emoji and pressing the backspace key deletes the emoji.
>
> However, in the current implementation, instead of deleting the emoji, pressing the backspace key deletes the last character of the token, causing the emoji to revert and the token to be exposed.
>
> For example, instead of deleting the entire "`{:ab_12:}`" token, only the last curly brace '`}`' is deleted, leaving "`{:ab_12:`" exposed.
>
> How should we handle deleting the entire token when pressing the backspace key?

You would need to intercept the backspace key event and modify the text input accordingly. That requires checking if the cursor is positioned right after an image (which represents a token) and, if so, deleting the entire token from the text, instead of just one character.

Update the `onValueChange` callback of the `BasicTextField` by:

- detecting if the backspace key is pressed.
- checking if the cursor is immediately after an image (token).
- modifying, if the above conditions are true, modif the `inputText` to remove the entire token.

That would be:

```kotlin
BasicTextField(
    value = inputText,
    onValueChange = { newText ->
        if (newText.length < inputText.length) { // backspace was pressed
            val cursorPosition = inputText.length // current cursor position is at the end of the current text
            val tokenRegex = Regex("\\{:(\\w+_\\d+):\\}")
            val matches = tokenRegex.findAll(inputText).toList()
            
            var tokenToDelete: MatchResult? = null
            for (match in matches) {
                if (cursorPosition == match.range.last + 1) {
                    tokenToDelete = match
                    break
                }
            }

            inputText = if (tokenToDelete != null) {
                // Delete the entire token
                inputText.removeRange(tokenToDelete.range)
            } else {
                // Default behavior, delete last character
                newText
            }
        } else {
            // Not a backspace or cursor is not behind an image, default behavior
            inputText = newText
        }
    },
    // Rest of the BasicTextField code
)
```

I assume here that the cursor is at the end of the text, which is a common scenario. However, if you need to handle cursor positions in the middle of the text, you would need to adjust the `cursorPosition` accordingly by tracking cursor movements.

You might also need to handle more complex scenarios, such as text selection and deletion, in which case the logic would become more involved and you would need to handle the ranges of selected text.

---

> The part that concerns me the most is when the user moves the cursor arbitrarily.
> In the Slack app, even if the user moves the cursor and presses the backspace key, it still works correctly. I'm not sure if this direction is actually correct.

To handle arbitrary cursor positions when the backspace key is pressed, you would modify the `onValueChange` function to determine if the cursor is directly following a token. If it is, then the whole token should be deleted instead of a single character.

```kotlin
BasicTextField(
    value = inputText,
    onValueChange = { newText ->
        val cursorPosition = it.selection.start // assuming `it` is the TextFieldValue
        if (newText.length < inputText.length) { // backspace was pressed
            val tokenRegex = Regex("\\{:(\\w+_\\d+):\\}")
            val matches = tokenRegex.findAll(inputText).toList()

            // Find the token that is immediately before the cursor
            val tokenBeforeCursor = matches.lastOrNull { match ->
                cursorPosition == match.range.last + 1
            }

            inputText = if (tokenBeforeCursor != null) {
                // Delete the entire token
                val tokenRange = tokenBeforeCursor.range
                StringBuilder(inputText).delete(tokenRange.first, tokenRange.last + 1).toString()
            } else {
                // No token before cursor, default behavior
                newText
            }
        } else {
            // Not a backspace or cursor is not behind a token, default behavior
            inputText = newText
        }
    },
    // Rest of the BasicTextField code
)
```

The `it.selection.start` provides the current cursor position within the `TextFieldValue`. When backspace is pressed (detected by a decrease in text length), it looks for a token right before the cursor.

- If such a token is found, it is removed entirely from the `inputText`.
- If no such token is found, the function defaults to the normal behavior of deleting the last character.

That should work correctly no matter where the cursor is placed in the text field, effectively mimicking the behavior observed in the Slack application.

---

> How can I get the "it" as TextFieldValue? Is 'inputText' TextFieldValue type? Where did you define the "it"?

In the context of the `BasicTextField`'s `onValueChange` lambda, `it` refers to the new value of the text field, typically provided as a `String`.
To get the `TextFieldValue`, which includes both the text and the selection range, the lambda needs to be adjusted to receive two parameters instead of one.

In Kotlin, when a lambda has a single parameter, you can use `it` to refer to that parameter.

The `BasicTextField` composable does have an overload that provides a `TextFieldValue` which contains both the text and selection range ( [third overload in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/package-summary.html#BasicTextField(androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextFieldValue,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush,kotlin.Function1))).

The `BasicTextField` function accepts an `onValueChange` callback that operates with either a `String` (for the simpler overload) or a `TextFieldValue` (for the more complex overload) but not both simultaneously in a single callback.

Using the `TextFieldValue` overload:

```kotlin
BasicTextField(
    value = textFieldValue, // TextFieldValue contains both the text and selection information
    onValueChange = { updatedValue ->
        // Logic to handle backspace and delete tokens goes here

        // Example pseudocode for handling token deletion:
        /*
        if (backspaceDetected && cursorIsAfterToken) {
            val newText = deleteTokenAtCursor(updatedValue.text, updatedValue.selection.start)
            textFieldValue = textFieldValue.copy(text = newText, selection = TextRange(newCursorPos))
        } else {
            textFieldValue = updatedValue
        }
        */
    },
    // Other parameters like textStyle, modifier, ...
)
```

`textFieldValue` is a state variable of type `TextFieldValue`, managed through `remember` and `mutableStateOf`. The `onValueChange` callback receives the updated `TextFieldValue` after each user input.
Inside this callback, you would implement the logic to detect a backspace action and whether the cursor is positioned right after a token. If both conditions are met, you should modify the text to remove the token and update the cursor position accordingly.

Comment: One more question, In the Slack app, placing the cursor directly after an emoji and pressing the backspace key deletes the emoji. However, in the current implementation, instead of deleting the emoji, pressing the backspace key deletes the last character of the token, causing the emoji to revert and the token to be exposed. For example, instead of deleting the entire "{:ab_12:}" token, only the last curly brace '}' is deleted, leaving "{:ab_12:" exposed. How should we handle deleting the entire token when pressing the backspace key?

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, the part that concerns me the most is when the user moves the cursor arbitrarily. In the Slack app, even if the user moves the cursor and presses the backspace key, it still works correctly. I'm not sure if this direction is actually correct.

Comment: How can I get the "it" as TextFieldValue? Is 'inputText' TextFieldValue type? Where did you define the "it"?

Comment: @dev.farmer Sorry for the delay: I have edited the answer to address your last comment.

Comment: Hmm... It seems that there is no BasicTextField defined in the form of a lambda that provides both String and TextFieldValue in onValueChange. There are three types of BasicTextField defined in the Reference, but none of them match this description. (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/package-summary.html)

Comment: @dev.farmer True, the third overload should work. I have edited the answer accordingly.